# Heatmap: take axis from dataframe indexes

Tags: python, dataframe, heatmap

I have renamed the indexes of the dataframe A and plottet it as a heatmap:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]))

columns = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.635,  1.27 ,  1.905])
rows = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.635])

A.columns = columns
A.index = rows

plt.imshow(A)
```

[image]

The x Axis of the plot shows the values of the dataframe at 0, 1, 2, 3 and the y Axis at 0, 1

How can I change the values of the axes to the ones of the dataframe?

In want the values on the x-axis to be on 0, 0.635, 1.27, 1.905 and the y-axis on 0, 0.635

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn is preferable to matplotlib.pyplot for making heatmaps in my opinion.

**If you wanted to use seabobrn**

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.heatmap(A, yticklabels = rows, xticklabels = columns)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Using seaborn heatmap instead of imshow leads to other problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892428/generate-same-surface-plot-in-matlab-and-python Is there a way to do it with imshow?

Comment: The *extent* option is a way to do it with imshow:

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    A = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]))
    
    columns = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.635,  1.27 ,  1.905])
    rows = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.635])
    
    A.columns = columns
    A.index = rows
    
    plt.imshow(A, extent = [columns.min() , columns.max() , rows.min(), rows.max()])
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7lcO.png